# Doubly Linked List in java implementation

Tags: java, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to find my to understand and start coding my assignment. We were asked to make a program for score game to set (String name, int score)in descending order. We are restricted to make it as a Doubly Linked List and the node data contain Name and Score, implementation we will do is storing them in descending order, add node, delete node, get node in i position. What I'm thinking of right now, is it a good idea to get the name and score as a HashMap? Am I able to do the implementation in an efficient way?If not HashMap how to store name and score in one node and make the implementations?

Answer (score 0):

> how to store name and score in one node...

```
class Node {
    public final String name;
    public final int score;

    public Node(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

Of course, you might want to add some other fields and probably some methods if you want to link your `Node` objects to one another in a doubly linked list.

Comment: Better yet, abstract away the notion of Node and make the node have a generic type where the type is some object with both fields `name` and `score`. You'd add a constructor that takes in an object of the generic type. E.g. `public class Node<T>{ .... }`

Comment: @LucasCrawford, sure, but the OP is looking for homework help for an intro to data structures class.  Using generics is a more sophisticated solution, but more sophistication is not always an improvement.

Comment: Fair enough, it's why I left a comment and not an answer :p

Comment: @jameslarge Thank you James. But could not get the idea how can I show descending order of my nodes according to the score, I need to show the score and name, how are they connected? For sure, if I want to to return the value of positions 2 for example, how is the name and score will be returned? I feel so lost although I have read so many resources in this chapter for more than 3 times. Your help is apperciated.

Comment: @DoeJ, That question is beyond the scope of stackoverflow.  According to the charter of this group, we can answer questions like, "Why do I get this error message ... when I try to compile this method ...?" or "Why does this method ... throw a NullPointerException when I call it with this string ...?", but we can't teach you Java, and we can't teach you how to write code, which, it sounds like, is where you need help right now.